# Sentence structure, and meaning

Tags: sentence-meaning, sentence-structure

> It's a good thing you did, when you taught me how to play guitar. I learned a lot.
>
> It's a good thing you did teaching me how to play guitar. I learned a lot.
>
> It's a good thing you did, teaching me how to play guitar. I learned a lot.

Do all the above sentences mean the same thing?
Are all of them correct?

Comment: Are you saying it's a good thing because it is useful for you or because it was a good deed by your friend? Your woringd sounds more like deed.

Comment: I meant it was useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All of your sentences are understandable meaning the deed that someone did by teaching you how to play the guitar was generous.

> It's a good thing you did, when you taught me how to play guitar. I learned a lot.

has the meaning that the gesture was good *at the time* that they taught you.

> It's a good thing you did teaching me how to play guitar. I learned a lot.
>   It's a good thing **that** you did, teaching me how to play guitar. I learned a lot.

describe it in a more smooth way and also means the "goodness" of it continues to the present.

> **You did a good thing by** teaching me how to play guitar. I learned a lot.

is closer to how a native would say it.

Answer (score 0):

All of the above mean the same thing and are more or less correct.  The first option is a little awkward, possibly just because of usage: the other two options are more commonplace, so the first one looks odd.  It would work better if phrased more directly:

> You did a good thing when you taught me how to play guitar.

That sounds natural, but also reads as a bit strong.  The other two are more indirect and casual, and I would say the final sentence, **It's a good thing you did, teaching me how to play guitar**, is the best, as the comma separates the two phrases.

Good to be aware: the sentence structure there comes off as pretty informal. It would sound natural if spoken aloud or written in a text message—something you'd say to thank a friend or peer.  But it might be too casual for formal writing.  In that case, I would go with the *"You did a good thing when..."* sentence.  It is the clearest and most direct, which is typically the standard for formal English style.

---

*A deeper investigation of usage:*

Breaking down the sentence, you have three parts:

> (It is a good thing) (*[that]* you did) (teaching me to play guitar)

As I mentioned before, those first two parts can be worded **You did a good thing** to be more direct—at the possible cost of putting more stress and attention on the person you're speaking to.

The final part of the sentence is a [gerund phrase](http://www.gingersoftware.com/content/grammar-rules/nouns/gerund-phrase/) that has also been moved out of place.  Its 'proper' location is actually being taken up by the pronoun **it** of **it's a good thing you did**, meaning that a simpler version of the sentence would read:

> Teaching me to play guitar is a good thing you did.

That, however, sounds extremely stilted.  Typically, the 'point' of a sentence goes at its end, and the sentence above looks less like someone thanking another for a guitar lesson and more like the analysis of a good-thing-identifying robot.